# Why the channel in the example code of tokio::sync::Notify is a mpsc?

Tags: rust, rust-tokio

I'm learning the synchronizing primitive of tokio. From [the example code of `Notify`](https://docs.rs/tokio/1.22.0/tokio/sync/struct.Notify.html#examples), I found it is confused to understand why `Channel<T>` is mpsc.

```rust
use tokio::sync::Notify;

use std::collections::VecDeque;
use std::sync::Mutex;

struct Channel<T> {
    values: Mutex<VecDeque<T>>,
    notify: Notify,
}

impl<T> Channel<T> {
    pub fn send(&self, value: T) {
        self.values.lock().unwrap()
            .push_back(value);

        // Notify the consumer a value is available
        self.notify.notify_one();
    }

    // This is a single-consumer channel, so several concurrent calls to
    // `recv` are not allowed.
    pub async fn recv(&self) -> T {
        loop {
            // Drain values
            if let Some(value) = self.values.lock().unwrap().pop_front() {
                return value;
            }

            // Wait for values to be available
            self.notify.notified().await;
        }
    }
}
```

- If there are elements in values, the consumer tasks will take it away
- If there is no element in values, the consumer tasks will yield until the producer nitify it

But after I writen some test code, I found in no case the consumer will lose the notice from producer.

Could some one give me test code to prove the above `Channel<T>` fail to work well as a mpmc?

---

The following code shows why it is unsafe to use the above `channel` as mpmc.

```rust
use std::sync::Arc;
#[tokio::main]
async fn main() {
    let mut i = 0;
    loop{
        let ch = Arc::new(Channel {
            values: Mutex::new(VecDeque::new()),
            notify: Notify::new(),
        });

        let mut handles = vec![];

        for i in 0..100{
            if  i % 2 == 1{
                for _ in 0..2{
                    let sender = ch.clone();
                    tokio::spawn(async move{
                        sender.send(1);
                    });
                }
            }else{
                for _ in 0..2{
                    let receiver = ch.clone();
                    let handle = tokio::spawn(async move{
                        receiver.recv().await;
                    });
                    handles.push(handle);
                }
            }
        }

        futures::future::join_all(handles).await;
        i += 1;
        println!("No.{i} loop finished.");
    }
}
```

Not running the next loop means that there are consumer tasks not finishing, and consumer tasks miss a notify.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Quote from the documentation you linked:

> If you have two calls to `recv` and two calls to `send` in parallel, the following could happen:
>
> 1. Both calls to `try_recv` return `None`.
> 2. Both new elements are added to the vector.
> 3. The `notify_one` method is called twice, adding only a single permit to the Notify.
> 4. Both calls to `recv` reach the Notified future. One of them consumes the permit, and the other sleeps forever.

Replace `try_recv` with `self.values.lock().unwrap().pop_front()` in our case; the rest of the explanation stays identical.

The third point is the important one: Multiple calls to `notify_one` only result in a single token if no thread is waiting yet. And there is a short time window where it is possible that multiple threads already checked for the existance of an item but aren't waiting yet.

Comment: I think the above document is about the channel uses `notify_on_sent` instead of `notify`. The method `try_recv ` and `notify_one ` are never been called in the code block I given.

Comment: @spongecaptain Yes, but the point is the same. Replace `try_recv` with `self.values.lock().unwrap().pop_front()`. The rest should apply 100%. I'm not sure why you think that `notify_one` is never called in your code, it's the last line of `send`.

Comment: I got it wrong, `notify_one` is been called, what I meant is the `try_recv` method is not been called.

Comment: Anyway, when producer call `send` method, if there are waiting consumers, the producers will just wakeup the consumer immediately. If there are no waiting consumers, the producers can add elements into deque many times, but add only a single permit to the Notify. And when consumers come to call `recv`, because there are elements in the deque, they can just take elements away and don't need a permit of Notify.

So, the elements in the channel are safe, can not be lost. So what is the problem of the above code works as a pmsc.

Comment: The problem is not if the consumers are already waiting, the problem is if the consumers already checked but aren't waiting yet. Then multiple calls of `notify_one()` will be combined into one.

Comment: @spongecaptain Updated my answer to provide a little more explanation.

Comment: Tank you very much, I got you point. The call of `pop_front()` and `notified()` is not atomic and notify can have one permit at most, that causes the receiver lose a notify.

Comment: @spongecaptain Exactly :)

Comment: Never mind, you solved my problem, and thank you a lot. The concurrent problem is hard to testify.

Comment: Yah, concurrency is hard in general. Rust makes a lot of guarantees that removes undefined behaviour like double-free and race conditions, but it doesn't give you a deadlock-free guarantee.